# DotNetNuke 7 skinning tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dotnetnuke

I'm looking for a decent tutorial on creating skins for DotNetNuke 7. I've not been able to find anything for the most up to date version of dnn and although I've had some success modifying existing skins, it would be a lot easier to be able to build them from scratch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately for DNN Skins, tutorials are hard to come by

Comment: This is a great step-by-step tutorial for beginners: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/2671/DotNetNuke-Skinning-101-Part-1.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure how soon you need this by, but I'll try to write a blog about it.

Comment: hey.. did u find anything helpful.. I also need to design skin from start

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm not going to go into too much detail, but I'll define some of the key elements about `DotNetNuke Skinning` and some of the potential problems you may encounter.

A skin can be written in one of two ways, `html` or an `ascx`.  The most common way is through an `ascx`.

- `html` : When you utilize this method, any changes you make within the skin will not be applied until `DotNetNuke` parses the skin.  When `DotNetNuke` does this parse, it will reference your manifest to correctly parse all of the values so it displays.
- `ascx` : This way does not need to be parsed, the changes you make will instantly go live.  Which makes manipulation easier.  However, this will still contain an a manifest to define your content as well.

Now, the easiest way to imagine `DotNetNuke` structure is through `Panes` and `Containers`.  Essentially a `Pane` will always be wrapped within a `Container`.

**But how do I design a skin?**

A few things to note, with `DotNetNuke` you tend to not design a site for exactly that page- You create more elaborate structures that can be used in a more general sense.  For example:

[image: Image of Web-Site]

So with the above image, you see a few key elements such as:

1. Logo
2. Search
3. Login
4. Menu
5. Banner
6. Grouping of three Content.
7. Grouping of four Content.
8. Another piece of Content.
9. Footer which is grouped by four as well.

So essentially we have a fairly easy data structure.  Which would usually include some fairly basic organization.  But my question is, how do you account or mobile devices or different page layouts such as:

[image: Social Profile]

Now you have a slightly more complex issue.  Well, `DotNetNuke` really kept a few considerations- Keep the developer as a developer, the designer as a designer.  Which allows large groups working with a site the flexibility without destroying one another work.

In every `DotNetNuke` skin you'll see these:

```
<%@ Control language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGO" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Logo.ascx" %>
```

What are those?  Well, the first is defining our `ascx`.  The important thing is the second one.  Essentially `DotNetNuke` has tokens available, these tokens will allow the skin to reflect changes made within `DotNetNuke` in it's interface.

So when we are referencing the core location, rather then a static object.  This allows the `DotNetNuke` interface to automatically input the logo in the location.

**Whoa, you lost me- If that is just a reference how do we specify the location?**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LOGO" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Logo.ascx" %>
```

Will reference our object.  To specify the location within our site you would do this:

```
<div class = "example_logo">
    <dnn:LOGO runat="server" id="dnnLOGO" BorderWidth="0" />
</div>
```

So we are essentially wrapping our token object in a `div` element.  Then we are actually calling our token.  This will physically place the logo from `DotNetNuke` interface into your site now.

This essentially eliminates the static approach, and allows it to become dynamic.

**So these are important, but how do I create the structure?**

```
<div id="Origin">
    <div class="Wrapper">
         <div id="Origin-Header">
            <div class="origin-header clearfix">

                 <!-- Header Elements -->
                 <div class=origin-logo>
                      <dnn:LOGO runat=server" id="dnnLOGO" BorderWidth="0" />
                 </div>
                 <div class="origin-login">
                       <dnn:LANGUAGE runat="server" id="dnnLANGUAGE" showMenu="false" showLinks="true" />
                       <dnn:LOGIN runat="server" id="dnnLOGIN" CssClass="login" /> |                      <dnn:USER runat="server" id="dnnUSER" CssClass="user" />
                       <dnn:SEARCH runat="server" id="dnnSEARCH" UseDropDownList="true" ShowSite="false" ShowWeb="false" />
                  </div>
            </div>
       </div>

        !-- Banner -->
        <div id = "Origin-Banner">
              <div class = "origin-banner-pane" id="origin-banner-pane" runat="server" />
        </div>
```

So the above is an example to get you started.  As you see your using your essential knowledge to build the site-structure.  Your just filling in the `DotNetNuke Tokens` into your design.  Then where you'd like the `DotNetNuke` modules to fill your sites data from the `DotNetNuke` interface is within those `Panes`.

Now the next important aspect will be the essential packaging of your skin.  This will actually ensure it works correctly once it is installed.

You can get more information from http://www.dotnetnuclear.com and http://www.dnnchat.com

Hopefully this provides the basics to get you started.  Which leaves the packaging and manifest left.

Hopefully this points you in right direction and helps.

Feel free to ask questions or follow those sites to try and get more information on the subject.

Comment: You could also check the DotNetNuke video library.

Comment: Mostly because I don't recall if I added it, but `DotNetNuke` requires a `ContentPane` to be defined within the *skin*.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably to look at the existing skins that ship with DotNetNuke as a start.
To create a new skin just go to the /Portals/_default/skins area and copy one of these directories paste and rename it to something unique. This should now show up in your skin selector.  90% of the .ascx skin files are just HTML/CSS. You can then modify the skin.css file and ASCX files as necessary to get your desired look.  To make a new skin option just create a new .ascx file.

You could also purchase a skin or two and take a look at how those were developed.

Comment: I think that's the way to go. You need to be familiar with basic module creation for DNN though.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris Hammond points out in the first comment, these tutorials are hard to come by.  @Chris - Thanks for writing the Module Template.  The community and I appreciate it.

I have been trying to learn about DNN skins myself and came across the DNN Hero website that has a good basic video tutorial about how to create a skin for a site.

It can be found here: http://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/tabid/259/ArticleID/80/1-How-to-create-my-first-skin-in-DotNetNuke-Part-1-6.aspx

I don't think this series is in the free set of videos, so you may have to subscribe to get it.  I am a subscriber and have not been disappointed.  If you need an introduction to skins or anything else DNN, the site is really informative.